# Change field name in django admin

Tags: database, django, django-models, python-3.x, django-admin

I am customizing django admin and I would like to change the display name of my fields.
I think the answer is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) but I can't find it.
I already change the table name thanks to Meta class. I have also ordered fields, gathered them, collapsed them...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What I was looking for is :

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Nom")
```

Thanks anyway for your help !

Comment: Worth noting that this will also change the label in all your non-admin forms (and anywhere else you use the verbose_name).

Answer (score 14):

Setting `verbose_name` on the model field, as in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18593858), does work, but it has some disadvantages:

- It will also affect the field label in non-admin forms, as mentioned in the comment
- It changes the definition of the model field, so it results in a new migration

If you *only* want to change the display name of the field on the *admin* site, you could either override the entire form, as suggested in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18516409), or simply modify the form field label by extending `ModelAdmin.get_form()`, as in the example below:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, change, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['my_model_field_name'].label = 'new name'
        return form
```

Note that this does not work if the field is in `readonly_fields` (at least in Django 2.2.16), because the field will be excluded `form.base_fields` (see [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L680)). In that case, one option would be to remove the field from `readonly_fields` and disable it instead, by adding another line inside `get_form()`:

```
form.base_fields['my_model_field_name'].disabled = True
```

Answer (score 6):

Look at Field.label.
See this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#label

Basically, it's

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='My Name')
```

But that requires extending the admin, which may be more than you want to do.

Comment: I have already founded this answer but where can I find those forms used to build the admin UI ? Basically, I don't need to call those for admin UI...
Somewhere in /usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin I assume...

Comment: You should install the django debug-toolbar. It will show you all the templates rendered and extended for any view.

Comment: I have trouble installing debug-toolbar but when it will I think it's gonna be usefull !