# Properly rename column name using display decorator in Django admin.py panel

Tags: django, django-admin, django-custom-user

I'm trying to rename the `IS STAFF` to `STAFF STATUS` here:
[image: Rename IS STAFF to STAFF STATUS]
I'm just wondering if it's possible to rename it from **`admin.py`** & NOT use the `verbose_name` inside the model.

I wrote this code in **`admin.py`**:

```py
@admin.register(User)
class CustomUserAdmin(DefaultUserAdmin):

    list_display = [
        'username',
        'RENAMED_EMAIL',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'RENAMED_STAFF',
        'is_active',
    ]

    @admin.display(description="EMAIL ADDRESS", ordering='-email')
    def RENAMED_EMAIL(self, obj):
        return obj.email

    @admin.display(
        description="STAFF STATUS",
        boolean=True,
        ordering='-is_staff',
        )
    def RENAMED_STAFF(self, obj):
        return obj.is_staff

list_editable = ['is_staff', 'is_active']
```

The **EMAIL ADDRESS** was renamed successfully but as I used `is_staff` in `list_editable`, I get this error:

```bash
ERRORS:
<class 'accounts.admin.CustomUserAdmin'>: (admin.E122) The value of 'list_editable[0]' refers to 'is_staff', which is 
not contained in 'list_display'.
```

Tried to use `RENAMED_STAFF` inside `list_editable` too, it results in another error:

```bash
ERRORS:
<class 'accounts.admin.CustomUserAdmin'>: (admin.E121) The value of 'list_editable[0]' refers to 'RENAMED_STAFF', which is not a field of 'accounts.User'.
```

What is the proper way to customize those column names?

Comment: Ali, Probably this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64247430/7106343) helps you

Comment: @AD Thanks, tho it's not what I was looking for. The problem was temporarily resolved, I found that if you don't write the `is_staff` in the Django model (`class User(AbstractUser)` inside **models.py**) & keep it as default, that column name would be **STAFF STATUS** by default. Still looking for the usage of the `display` decorator with `list_editable`;